# How can I determine which operations or processes prevent screen saver and sleep mode

Tags: process-explorer, sysinternals, process-monitor

My desktop will not enter sleep mode or fire up the screen saver.  To troubleshoot, I have run procmon and procexp from sysinternals in order to determine if some event is making the system think it is not idle.  I do not, however know which processes and/or operations prevent the system from entering sleep mode or screen saver.  Is there a document for this anywhere?

Comment: Have you tried shortening the screensaver time to least possible value?

Comment: Yes, I have tried changing the settings to 1 minute, the display is still on and unchanged the next morning.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the power options as shown here 
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976877#Powersetting

Comment: Thanks.  This was very helpful, and I did try using the commands.

Answer (score 0):

The responses here (including this one) do not answer the original question I had, but I was able to solve the problem and thought I would post that.

I was also having a problem with IE10 not reopening my tabs after restarting the browser even though I had set it to do so.  I read a post about checking the add-ons and disabling them one by one until the issue was resolved.  When I looked at the add-ons, I noticed one for the Logitech mouse I have called Setpoint.  Thinking that the problems might be related, I disabled that one first and BOTH of my problems disappeared, now screen saver and sleep mode work fine.  I have no idea why, though.